# Вызов и вывод объекта одного класса в другом классе(методе)

Tags: php, ооп, pdo

Имеется вот такой класс Dbtest подключения к бд через PDO. Так же имеется другой класс в котором я бы хотел бы соединяться с бд и делать выборку информации.И последнее после выборки хотелось бы вывести эту информацию для проверки. Так как маловато опыта в oop пытаюсь все освоить на практике)Проблема с вызовом обьектов класса и передачей информации из одного класса в другой.Для вывода в классе я использовал вот такую конструкцию:

```
$Db = new Dbtest();

$user = $Db->query("SELECT * FROM `good`");

print_r($user)
```

По сути метод getPriceWithVat класса Testcon должен подключиться к бд сделать выборку и вывести ее для проверки.(Не судите строго я новичек)

```
<?php


class Dbtest
{
    private $link;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect()
    {
        $params = require_once "db_params.php";

        $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']}";

        $this->link = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password']);

        return $this;
    }
    public function execute($sql)
    {
        $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);

        return $sth->execute();
    }
    public function query($sql)
    {
        $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);

        $sth->execute();

        $result = $sth->ftchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return  $result;
    }

}


class Testcon
{


    public  function getPriceWithVat(){



    }
}
```

Comment: ну так внутрь getPriceWithVat и закинуть ваш код $Db = new Dbtest(); return $user = $Db->query("SELECT * FROM good");

Comment: Ок это понятно а как вывести(для проверки) то что выводит метод?Я создаю объект $Db = new Testcon(); $Db->getPriceWithVat();
print_r($Db);Возвращается пустой объект. Пытаюсь вызвать метод класса возвращает Fatal error: Class 'Dbtest' not found in...

Comment: Однозначно плюсик за использование PDO. Хотел было тут же компенсировать его минусиком за записывания соединения в переменную объекта, но в комментах к ответу увидел, что Вы собираетесь сделать singleton. Это Вы правильно решили.

Comment: @АлександрБелинский однозначный жирный **минус**  за использование ПДО в качестве [*карго культа*](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement), который ни от чего не защищает.

Comment: @Ипатьев и не должен ни от чего защищать, если его "используют неправильно". Как и любая другая библиотека.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы использовать объект класса Dbtest в другом классе, его надо **передать в этот класс через конструктор.**

Никакое наследование тут не должно применяться. Наследование, вообще, самый неоднозначный и опасный из элементов ООП, и его не следует применять до тех пор, пока не будет четкого понимания основ.

Статический метод/синглтон это тоже так себе решение, сойдет для классического похапе-гуанокода, но если хочется учить правильный ООП, то класс для работы с БД надо передавать в другие классы в качестве *зависимости*.

Кроме того в классе есть много своих косяков.

- самый огромный минус - это подотовленные запросы, которые ничего не подготавливают. Весь смысл подготовленных запросов в том, что переменные никогда не вишутся в запросе, а **передаются отдельно**, в execute.
- правильный код соединения берем [отсюда](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql)
- до тех пор, пока в классе не реализовано 100% функциональности PDO, инстанс надо делать публичным
- не забываем про charset! Чтобы потом не бегать с вопросами, почему в базе вопросики
- выкидываем бессмысленную функцию connect, код переносим в конструктор

В итоге всю эту красоту надо переписать по крайней мере так

```
class DB
{
    public $link;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $params = require_once "db_params.php";
        $options = [
            \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];
        $dsn = "mysql:host={$params['host']};dbname={$params['dbname']};charset=$params['charset']";
        try {
             $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
             throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
        }
        $this->link = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['password'], $options);

    }

    public function execute($sql, $params = [])
    {
        $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);
        return $sth->execute($params);
    }
    public function getAll($sql, $params = [], $mode = PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    {
        return  $this->execute($sql, $params)->fetchAll($mode);
    }
}
```

Соответственно, в остальные классы передаем БД в конструктор

```
class Testcon
{
    protected $db;
    public function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public  function getPriceWithVat(){
        return $this->db->getAll("SELECT * FROM prices");
    }
}

$db = new DB();
$test = new Testcon($db);
$data = $test->getPriceWithVat();
```